Misunderstanding of length contraction in special relativity
Let us assume I get into a rocket, and I quickly reach a speed close to $c$. In my reference frame, I can reach a star at the end of the galaxy in a few days, due to length contraction (and observer at Earth would instead see it as a consequence of time dilation).
Assuming I didn't make a mistake with the above explanation, how could this be possible? I started with an object at a few thousand light years away, and after I accelerated for a short amount of time, that object is now only a few day lights away. Is this picture correct? If so then the star should have moved close to me at faster than $c$. This seems to be what happens too if you look at a Minkowski diagram as my axes get more and more oblique relative to those from my starting reference frame at Earth, when I accelerate. Something very basic is wrong with my reasoning, please help.
Note: I think this just another version of the spaceship paradox, but I am not sure.

Don't think about length contraction.  Just think about time dilation.  You know that nothing can travel faster than c, so the only way for you to reach the star in a few days in your time is if your time is dilated.  Some have used the explanation of length contraction in your frame to explain that you are not surpassing c, but this is just confusing.  Just think about time dilation in your frame.

@foolishmuse that is the answer to the question, not a comment.

@foolishmuse I am asking from my point of view. I understand I will see time dilation for the star, but how do I explain in my reference frame that I can reach an object that was originally unreachable? How can the distance change so fast in my own reference frame?

Something weird must be happening as I change from the reference frame of earth to my current one, as the simultaneity lines change?

@PatoGalmarini in your frame, the length will indeed appear contracted so that you can reach the star in what to you feels like mere days. From the rest frame of the star (or the earth, or any point in between), it will appear as if your journey takes thousands of years.

@paulina I understand that, please read my question more carefully. Also,  I added some clarification.

Re, "...if so then the star should have moved close to me at faster than ." The star hasn't moved. Your acceleration has changed the way you look at spacetime (i.e., it has transformed the coordinate system that describes your point of view.) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rh0pYtQG5wI

"I understand that..." It is not clear that you do. Your question, as written, really seems unrelated to the acceleration. I think that even more clarification is needed if your question is not just about basic Lorentz transformation...

@hft I stated that I started at rest with earth, and then I ended moving at almost c relative to earth, and the distance seemed to change just in between the small time during the acceleration. I have no idea how to be more clear.

I appreciate all the answers, I am not sure what made my question so unclear.

"...the small time..." What do you mean "the small time?" You are accelerating to the close to the speed of light from rest in a small amount of time?

@htf no, the rotation example made me realize the answer, at least to a level that I find satisfactory. I guess I don't express my ideas clearly, but my comments below the answer may give you a hint of the kind of answer I was looking for.  You just didn't read my question carefully enough, in my honest opinion.

@hft You had a good point, it is not really an answer to my question, even if somehow I found it helpful

I would like to reopen the question, I found the answer and I would like to write it

By the way, you can't quickly reach relativistic speeds. The human body can't tolerate sustained high acceleration. If you accelerate constantly at 1.5 g, after 201.38 days ship time (226.75 days Earth time), you've travelled ~0.25 light-years (in the Earth frame), your speed is ~0.693 c, and your current Lorentz gamma factor is ~1.3871. And of course, that requires a lot of energy. A ship doing 1.5 g has a "half-life" of ~163.5 days (ship time). That is, an ideal antimatter-powered ship has to annihilate half its mass every  163.5 days to sustain 1.5 g.

@PM2Ring Thanks for the info, but that was not the point of the question, imagine and ideal observer than does not need to interrupt his measurements to go to pee, and other incredible skills.

Yes, I get that, which is why I said "by the way". Also, I didn't post that info when you originally posted your question because I didn't want to send the discussion off on a tangent. ;)

Your intuition was correct. However, there is no single way to define distances in an accelerated frame of reference, Perhaps the most intuitive one is the one given by Rindler coordinates (See Below). These coordinates are derived under the assumption that the observer is accelerating with a constant proper acceleration, but this simplification does not detract from seeing the issues arising with the problem For a better description of these coordinates see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates.

Suppose the accelerated observer starts accelerating from rest with respect to some inertial system S.
An accelerated observer that uses Rindler coordinates will agree in the future with the distances (and clock rates) measured by an inertial observer that is instantaneously at rest with him (S’), that is, distances consistent with the length contracted distances (relative to the initial reference frame S).
The grid hiperbolas can be interpreted as observers moving at different proper accelerations relative to S, but our accelerated observer will see them all at rest relative to himself.
An inertial observer at S never sees these accelerated observers moving at a velocity faster than c. However, the reverse is not true. The accelerated observer will see Minkowski observers (those at rest at different positions at S) as following different hyperbolic secant curves (see pic below), the ones in the direction of motion get closer to him but the farther away they are the faster they move to catch up with the length contraction (basically an object uniformly contracts but the end located at the position of the observer does not move, whereas a point at the far end of the object needs to move the fastest to keep the contracting object not stretched.

We can calculate the peak velocity (which reaches a maximum at some point along the trajectory of the accelerated observer) of a static Minkowski observer (like a far away star originally at rest) using the Rindler coordinates (we depicted instead the Kottler–Møller coordinates which shift the Rindler coordinates so that our accelerated observer starts at  X=0.
Kottler–Møller coordinates


We can see that the metric itself predict a local speed of light with a value of c, but the coordinate speed of light in this system grows unbounded with the distance to the observer. This in analogous to what happens in a contracting universe. On the opposite direction, towards the Rindler horizon, the speed of light we see becomes smaller, and it reaches zero at the horizon (as in an expanding universe or as in a black hole horizon in  Schwarzschild coordinates)
By differentiating the equation on the right for $t$ and $x$ we can calculate the coordinate velocity seen by the accelerated observer of an object at rest on S and far from him.
Doing so we get
$$dx/dt=v_X=-\frac{\alpha T}{X} \sqrt(X^2-T^2)$$
With some algebra it is not difficult to show that an object located at a constant distance X will be perceived (by teh accelerated observer moving towards it) as having a maximum speed of $v_X=X\alpha/2$, at $T=X/\sqrt2$
Another way to define distances which might be more practical from the standpoint of physical measurement. A more natural notion of distance between two world lines is the radar distance. This is computed by sending a null geodesic from the world line of our observer (event A) to the world line of some small object, whereupon it is reflected (event B) and returns to the observer (event C). The radar distance is then obtained by dividing the round trip travel time, as measured by an ideal clock carried by our observer. This  system might seem more natural and practical, and the speed of light will remain c for any coordinates.
Radar coordinates (Lass coordinates)


This observer however  also suffers from non intuitive  issues.  For instance  the initial distances for a grid along $X$ for $T=\tau=0$, which are initially spaced for the inertial observer, are no longer equally spaced for the acceleration observer. The distances measured along a uniform grid (for the inertial observer) in the direction of acceleration will not be given uniform spacing by the accelerated observer.  The distances become smaller the farther away the object. If  the actual distance as measured by the inertial observer from the accelerated observer to a point at a distance D from that observer, then, even when they are both at rest relative to each other,  the distance  measured by the accelerated observer will depend  on position: the ratio $d’/d_0$, where $d_0$ is the inertial distance from the accelerating observer as measured by an inertial one, and d', that measured by the accelerated one, is $d’/d_0=\frac{ln(N)}{2N}$, where N is a number that measures how large is the distance from the observer compared with the initial position of teh accelerated observer.  That is, objects that we would normally put very far away, in the radar coordinates these faraway distances start very small.

I wonder why the vote down, can you at least point just one thing that is wrong

I believe it will clear up a lot of your confusion if you forget about spacetime for a few minutes and think about the analogous question in ordinary three-dimensional space.
Stand in Chicago facing north.  Los Angeles is on your left and New York is on your right.
Now change frames by turning 180 degrees.   In your new (inertial) frame, Los Angeles is on your right and New York is on your left.
If you insist on thinking about how things look from the non-inertial frame that traveled along with you as you were spinning, then Los Angeles and New York have each traveled along enormous semi-circles, landing in their new positions almost immediately.  Depending on how fast a spinner you are, they might even have traveled faster than light.
Moral:  If you insist on thinking in terms of non-inertial frames, be prepared for the world to look very weird.
Now back to your question:  There is a perfectly good inertial frame in which your journey is a thousand light years long, and another in which your journey is a a few light-days long.   If you insist on thinking in terms of the non-inertial frame that travels with you as you accelerate, the world is going to look very weird. You should have been prepared for that.

Exactly, this is spot-on.

This is a good point, I just realized that in a rotating system, far away objects will look as moving faster than c if they are very far away, and this should not be an issue. I did not expect this to be the case with linear motion though.

The only way to have a grid of clocks set up at a constant distance in my accelerated frame is if they are mounted on their own rockets so we all move together. Same with rods, I cannot have "passive" rods to measure distance.


If so then the star should have moved close to me at faster than c.

Note that if you invert the situation, and the star were accelerating to an inertial ship, it would not be coming faster than c. So, the use of this kind of symmetry (star is moving to me) is not correct when there is acceleration.
What happens is: to an inertial frame S' moving to the star close to c (with respect to the frame S Earth-star), the distance Earth-Star is already small. When accelerating, the ship changes from frame S to S'.
For each inertial frame the situation is symmetric, but changing frames breaks this symmetry.
The point is:
I can not say that the relative speed star - ship is faster than light because everytime when I measure the light from the star, its velocity is $c$. The meaning of 'faster than light' is being able to measure a faster than $c$ speed of incoming light.
On the other hand, I take $t'$ in my ship's time to reach the star with a relative velocity $v$ (after a supposed brief interval of acceleration), then it's distance (by definition) is $d' = vt'$ in ship's frame.
And after arriving, I can see that in the star clock (supposed previously synchronized with the Earth) the journey time is $t = \gamma t'$. So, the distance in the frame of the Earth must be: $d = vt$, which implies $$d' = \frac{d}{\gamma}$$.
I have to interpret the results as length contraction exactly because the light speed is always $c$.

But what happens in between the two inertial frames, that is, during acceleration? In my coordinate system the star is initially at a distance L, and at the end is at a distance L'. That distance was reduced in a small amount of proper time. How can I explain that in my own reference system? (I know it is non inertial). Does it mean that in a non inertial system I can measure speeds >c?

@Pato Galmarini I think that this is what you should really be asking, as nobody appears to be quite answering what I believe your original question to be about.

The question is: how to measure the relative velocity between ship and star at any moment? One way is by the blue shifting of the H spectrum. If you use the formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#Relativistic_longitudinal_Doppler_effect, the speed is never greater than c.

@Penguino yes, I guess I have communication issues, I noticed that, and I was wondering what made it so confusing.

the doppler effect is a good point, not the answer I was looking for, which was "what is wrong in my reasoning"

Please, see the edit in the answer.
